# C++ Key Input check

Tags: c++, user-input

I am writing a function that gets user input and performs an action according to what the user entered. I am using a case statement that checks what the user entered.

I am having difficulty seeing if the user pressed home, end, ins and del.  The default variable such as HOME, INSERT, DELETE and END don't seem to have an effect, but the arrow keys do, using LEFT and RIGHT. I am doing this in GNU/Linux. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you show the code you have it would be easier for people to help you, how are you reading user input for example

Comment: just from a getchar() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problems:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Compiled on GNU/Linux
//By: Saulius Grybas


int main()
{
        int key;
        bool done = false;

    while (!done)
    {

        key = getchar();

        switch (key){
                case HOME:
                        //Home key is pressed / perform action
                        done = true;
                        break;
               case END:
                        //END key is pressed / perform action
                        done = true;
                        break;
               case DEL:
                        //DEL key is presed / perform action
                        done = true;
                        break;
                case BACKSPACE:
                        //backspace is pressed / perform action
                        done = true;
                        break;
                default:
                        done = false;
                        break;
         }
                printf ("%d%s\n", key, " - Integer of key is pressed!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your constants HOME END DEL and BACKSPACE does not seem to be defined, was that your problem. For me the posted code does not compile, does it compile for you?

Comment: I know.  I am looking for the key codes that represent these keystrokes, so I can replace the "keystroke" with the key code.  For Example: case 0x10: //is enter, I believe, but I cant seem to get the characters above.  Also if I enter '\b' is backspace.

Comment: can you run

int c=getchar();
printf("code %d\n",c);

and see what you get? or is that your problem that getchar does not return when those keys are pressed?

Answer (score 0):

These define the scan codes (IBM PC) for the keys. All numbers are in decimal.

```
#define PAGE_UP     73
#define HOME        71
#define END         79
#define PAGE_DOWN   81
#define UP_ARROW    72
#define LEFT_ARROW  75
#define DOWN_ARROW  80
#define RIGHT_ARROW 77
#define F1          59
#define F2          60
#define F3          61
#define F4          62
#define F5          63
#define F6          64
#define F7          65
#define F8          66
#define F9          67
#define F10         68

#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
```

Here are the Linux scan codes : http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/howlinuxworks/linux_hlkeycodes.html